# Index PDF file at the command line without using Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf

I have a process that involved opening PDF files in Adobe Acrobat Pro in order to add indexes.  This allows folks to search the PDFs and get results more quickly.

Is there a command line tool (preferably open source) that I can accomplish this with?  Initial searches have not yielded anything yet.

Comment: It may happen that this question will be killed and closed down by SO police volunteers (instead of transfering it to the [appropriate site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)). The first 'close' vote has already arrived. So my advice: if the close happens, rather ask on the "SoftwareRecommendations" link I provided above...